# Why calling the reduce method in the parallel stream with a mutable object as identity does not reserve the order in the result?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce, forkjoinpool

There is the following seemingly "correct" code:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6",
    "7","8","9","10","11","12");
String result = list.parallelStream()
   .reduce(new StringBuilder(), StringBuilder::append, 
       StringBuilder::append).toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

The problem of this snippet is that the *identity*, `new StringBuilder()`, in the `reduce` method call is *mutable*, thus the `result` is *undermined*, i.e. the order of the `result` does not preserve. But I cannot fully understand the reason, thus I am not able to visualize a case of producing the `result` with in the different order from the original `list`. So I drew the corresponding *map-reduce* diagram, which by chance got the `result` preserving the order:
[image]

**Question: First, I would like to confirm this diagram is correct. Second, if this diagram is correct, I would like to know where is the cause for this code snippet not always producing the `result` preserving the order**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your diagram is not correct - you assume that each parallel reduction starts with a new `StringBuilder`. Instead of that each parallel reduction starts **with the same identity element** - with the same StringBuilder (the one that you create and pass as the first parameter to the `reduce` method).

Each parallel stream calls `StringBuilder.append` on the (one and only) StringBuilder that you pass to the `reduce` method, thereby appending the currently encountered element to it.

The next step is combining partial results, also by calling `StringBuilder.append` on the same StringBuilder, appending copies of the contents of the StringBuilder onto itself.

---

To create the diagram that you have drawn, you would have to pass a `Supplier<StringBuilder>` as the first parameter to the reduce operation.

Actually, according to the comment from Holger, this is possible when using [Mutable Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction).

For this you don't call the reduce method, but rather the `collect` method:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6",
    "7","8","9","10","11","12");
String result = list.parallelStream()
   .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, 
       StringBuilder::append).toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) This is what I would like to know (Y)

Comment: It should be noted that supporting such mutable container is exactly what [*Mutable Reduction*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) is about, so `.collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append) .toString()` does the job. Which is exactly the same as `collect(Collectors.joining())`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: @Holger thanks for the information. I've included it in my answer