# Reduce vs Collect method on Parallel Streams vs Serial Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am failing to understand how reduce method work vs the collect method.
Given
`Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(Set.of("b", "c", "d"));`

Why does this code below produce firstResult= cdbcdb and secondResult= bcd

```
// Using reduce with StringBuilder
StringBuilder firstResult = set
        .parallelStream()
        .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s))
        // Requires Identity(StringBuilder), BiFunction, BinaryOperator
        .reduce(new StringBuilder(),
                (a, b) -> a.append(b),
                (a, b) -> a.append(b));

// Using collect with StringBuilder
StringBuilder secondResult = set
        .parallelStream()
        .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s))
        // collect requires Supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                (a, b) -> a.append(b),
                (a, b) -> a.append(b));
```

while this code below produce firstResult=bdc and secondResult=''

```
// Using reduce with StringBuilder
StringBuilder firstResult = set
        .parallelStream()
        .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s))
        // Requires Identity(StringBuilder), BiFunction, BinaryOperator
        .reduce(new StringBuilder(),
                (a, b) -> b.append(a),
                (a, b) -> a.append(b));


// Using collect with StringBuilder
StringBuilder secondResult = set
        .parallelStream()
        .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s))
        // collect requires Supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                (a, b) -> b.append(a),
                (a, b) -> a.append(b));
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Though the correct way to collect the appended `String` could be `String.join("", set)`. I am interested to understand *how* the buffered data varies with the `accumulator` changing from `a.append(b)` to `b.append(a)`.

Comment: @Naman For the reduce case, the identity is modified when `a.append(b)` is called and no change in case `b.append(a)`. The strange result is due to parallel stream and using mutable `StringBuilder` as Identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### To begin, the given program is modified to see what happen inside each scenario.

```java
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class ReduceVsCollect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(Set.of("b", "c", "d"));
        parallelReduceA_Append_B(set);
        parallelCollectA_Append_B(set);
        parallelReduceB_Append_A(set);
        parallelCollectB_Append_A(set);
    }

    private static void parallelReduceA_Append_B(Set<String> set) {
        System.out.println("-".repeat(80));
        System.out.println("Start parallelReduceA_Append_B");
        StringBuilder identity = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("identity hash: " + System.identityHashCode(identity));
        StringBuilder result = set
                .parallelStream()
                .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s))
                .reduce(identity,
                        (a, b) -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format("called accumulator, a hash:%s, a:%s, b:%s", System.identityHashCode(a), a, b));
                            return a.append(b);
                        },
                        (a, b) -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format("called combiner, a hash:%s, a:%s, b:%s", System.identityHashCode(a), a, b));
                            return a.append(b);
                        }
                );
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }

    private static void parallelCollectA_Append_B(Set<String> set) {
        System.out.println("-".repeat(80));
        System.out.println("Start parallelCollectA_Append_B");
        StringBuilder result = set
                .parallelStream()
                .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s))
                .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                        (a, b) -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format("called accumulator, a hash:%s, a:%s, b:%s", System.identityHashCode(a), a, b));
                            a.append(b);
                        },
                        (a, b) -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format("called combiner, a hash:%s, a:%s, b:%s", System.identityHashCode(a), a, b));
                            a.append(b);
                        });
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }

    private static void parallelReduceB_Append_A(Set<String> set) {
        System.out.println("-".repeat(80));
        System.out.println("Start parallelReduceB_Append_A");
        StringBuilder identity = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("identity hash: " + System.identityHashCode(identity));
        StringBuilder result = set
                .parallelStream()
                .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s))
                .reduce(identity,
                        (a, b) -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format("called accumulator, a hash:%s, a:%s, b:%s", System.identityHashCode(a), a, b));
                            return b.append(a);
                        },
                        (a, b) -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format("called combiner, a hash:%s, a:%s, b:%s", System.identityHashCode(a), a, b));
                            return b.append(a);
                        });
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }

    private static void parallelCollectB_Append_A(Set<String> set) {
        System.out.println("-".repeat(80));
        System.out.println("Start parallelCollectB_Append_A");
        StringBuilder result = set
                .parallelStream()
                .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s))
                .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                        (a, b) -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format("called accumulator, a hash:%s, a:%s, b:%s", System.identityHashCode(a), a, b));
                            b.append(a);
                        },
                        (a, b) -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format("called combiner, a hash:%s, a:%s, b:%s", System.identityHashCode(a), a, b));
                            b.append(a);
                        });
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

### Result

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start parallelReduceA_Append_B
identity hash: 1642360923
called accumulator, a hash:1642360923, a:, b:c
called accumulator, a hash:1642360923, a:, b:b
called accumulator, a hash:1642360923, a:cb, b:d
called combiner, a hash:1642360923, a:cbd, b:cbd
Result: cbdcbd
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start parallelCollectA_Append_B
called accumulator, a hash:1940447180, a:, b:c
called accumulator, a hash:572416449, a:, b:b
called accumulator, a hash:1940447180, a:c, b:d
called combiner, a hash:572416449, a:b, b:cd
Result: bcd
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start parallelReduceB_Append_A
identity hash: 245565335
called accumulator, a hash:245565335, a:, b:c
called accumulator, a hash:245565335, a:, b:b
called accumulator, a hash:476402209, a:c, b:d
called combiner, a hash:1490180672, a:b, b:dc
Result: dcb
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start parallelCollectB_Append_A
called accumulator, a hash:358699161, a:, b:c
called accumulator, a hash:1802696844, a:, b:b
called accumulator, a hash:358699161, a:, b:d
called combiner, a hash:1802696844, a:, b:
Result:
```

### Explanation of different scenario:

#### 1. Reduce with `a.append(b)` result in "cdbcdb" :

Repeated sequence is due to using mutable *identity* - `new StringBuilder()` in `reduce`([Refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53240634/why-calling-the-reduce-method-in-the-parallel-stream-with-a-mutable-object-as-id#answer-53242041)). The value of `identity` keeps changing when `accumulator` is called. All intermediate result is also stored in `identity`, so when combiner is called, two sequence is shown.

#### 2. Collect with `a.append(b)` result in "bcd" :

As [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) state,

> Performs a mutable reduction operation on the elements of this stream. A mutable reduction is one in which the reduced value is a mutable result container, such as an ArrayList, and elements are incorporated by updating the state of the result rather than by replacing the result

Hence this is a valid scenario to use `StringBuilder`

#### 3. Reduce with `b.append(a)` result in "bdc" :

This time `identity` is not modified due to swapping the parameter, and intermediate result is stored in the `StringBuilder` in `.map(s -> new StringBuilder(s))`, hence no repeated sequence is shown.

#### 4. Collect with `b.append(a)` result in "" :

Refer to the [psuedocode of collect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)),

```
     R result = supplier.get();
     for (T element : this stream)
         accumulator.accept(result, element);
     return result;
```

In the accumulator, we called `b.append(a)` which means result(a) is **never** modified, so it keeps its initial value as `new StringBuilder()`.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the detailed and awesome explanation. Very much Appreciated thank you!